# Docker container started running in ubuntu . But then again saying "No such container"

Tags: docker, container

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
sudo docker build -t ssh-mock . --no-cache
sudo docker run --rm -d --name ssh-mock -p 9991:9991 ssh-mock
sudo docker logs -f ssh-mock
```

I ran these commands to build , run and view the logs. As shown in the picture as I understand it started running, but then again it is saying that "No such container"

Comment: Please include output of `docker ps -a`

Comment: @ArturMeinild  Added please check

Comment: Please include output of `docker version`, `snap list` and `apt policy docker.io`.

Comment: Also check what's in syslog when you try to start the container - are there any error messages?

Comment: Since you use the --rm flag it means that your container is deleted after its main process stops.  Are you sure that yout containers "ENTRYPOINT" is running correctly ?

Comment: Yeah running without `--rm` would be wise for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Added the responses of docker version, snap list and apt policy docker.io

Comment: @dominz88  This command has worked before.   I had to reinstall ubuntu recently and now it is not working

Comment: The container doesn't come up. Run without `--rm`. Then it will show in the list with `docker ps -a`. Then you can troubleshoot why the container doesn't start.